# How to improve this linear fit (considering error bars) to make it more robust?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression, data-fitting

I'm trying to perform a linear fit of a set of measures as define below:

```
def leastsq_lin_fit(x,y,yerr=[]):
    fit_func = lambda p, x: p[0] * x  + p[1] 
    model=scipy.odr.Model(fit_func)
    if len(yerr)>0: data = scipy.odr.RealData(x, y, sy=yerr)
    else: data = scipy.odr.RealData(x, y)
    odr = scipy.odr.ODR(data, model, beta0=[0., 1.])
    out = odr.run()

    a=out.beta[0]
    aErr=out.sd_beta[0]
    b=out.beta[1]
    bErr=out.sd_beta[1]
```

but I noticed that when I parse the yerr to the fitting routine, I get a weird result as shown below:
[image]

while when I fitt without considering the error bar of my y values, I get:
[image]

I'm not saying the first result is wrong, I suspect this result is driven by the fact that the error bars in my data are probably too small to fit a meaningful line (in particular for small X values). What I would like to understand is, because this is the data I have to work with, how can I improve this fit (considering the error bars) to make it more robust. How would you fit such distribution with a linear function?

[Here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/827186c4a002ef882e198814c022d78d20200826170928/dcf8fa) you can download the file containing the data I used to make these plots and that can be loaded through:

```
with open('test.np', 'rb') as f:
    xdata = np.load(f)
    ydata = np.load(f)
    yerr = np.load(f)
```

(If there is a better way to upload the file please let me know).

Comment: Why You are using here ODR instead of standard linear regression?

Comment: probably because I'm "ignorant", I look online for example and they were using it. What do you mean by "standard linear regression"?

Comment: Difference between ODR and classic least squares regression has good explanation here:  http://blog.rtwilson.com/orthogonal-distance-regression-in-python/